# defined another init method, but initWithNibName:bundle is still called by system

Tags: ios, objective-c

in SomeViewController, i want to use a customized init method, meanwhile disable `-initWithNibName:bundle:` :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"use -initWithChannel:tag: instead");
    return nil;
}

- (instancetype)initWithChannel:(NSString *)channel tag:(NSString *)tag
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.channel = channel;
        self.tag = tag;
    }
    return self;
}
```

but when i call `-initWithChannel:tag:`, `-initWithNibName:bundle:` is called right after `-[UIViewController init]`, why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `[super init]` the initialization of your `UIViewController` calls `initWithNibName`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704865/uiviewcontroller-super-init-calls-self-initwithnibname-bundle).

Comment: but why does it call my `initWithNibName` not `[UIViewController initWithNibName]` ?

Comment: Inheritance. It calls [self initWithNibName] so if you override it, it will call yours.

Comment: so in super method, if it calls `self`, it is really calls `parent` is this situation?

Comment: it calls initWithNibName on your instance, which would generally call `[super initWithNibName]`

Comment: u really helped, but ur answer is not good enough to mark as accepted, in fact, it is related to the behavior of super / self, even the runtime, so if u can edit ur answer more detail, i'll mark it as accepted.